# showing the desktop version for tablet computers

Tags: mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to display the desktop version of the site if the user is accessing the site from a tablet computer. The method contextCheck_WithDirectMethod does return false as it is supposed to but the mobile version is still being shown on my ipad. Any help on how to solve this will be very much appreciated.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Func<HttpContextBase, bool> contextCheckDelegate = contextCheck_WithDirectMethod;
        DefaultDisplayMode mobileMode = new DefaultDisplayMode("mobile");
        mobileMode.ContextCondition = contextCheckDelegate;
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(mobileMode);
    }
    public bool contextCheck_WithDirectMethod(HttpContextBase objHttpContextBase)
    {

        bool isTablet = false;
        string varBrowserAgent = objHttpContextBase.Request.UserAgent;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(varBrowserAgent))
        {
            varBrowserAgent = varBrowserAgent.ToString().ToLower();
            if (varBrowserAgent.Contains("ipad") || (varBrowserAgent.Contains("android") && !varBrowserAgent.Contains("mobile")))
            {
                isTablet = true;
                objHttpContextBase.ClearOverriddenBrowser();
            }
        }

        if (!isTablet)
        {
            if (objHttpContextBase.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(varBrowserAgent))
        {
            varBrowserAgent = varBrowserAgent.ToString().ToLower();

            if (objHttpContextBase.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true || varBrowserAgent.Contains("ipod") || varBrowserAgent.Contains("ipad")
             || varBrowserAgent.Contains("iphone") || varBrowserAgent.Contains("android") || varBrowserAgent.Contains("iemobile"))
            {
                if (isTablet)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Display Mode logic looks for matches in the order they are registered. The default Mobile mode is registered before you add yours, so your new Mobile mode is never evaluated.

The general pattern is to insert your new Display Mode at index 0 rather than add a Display Mode. Instead of:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(mobileMode);
```

use:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, mobileMode);
```

Alternatively, you can change the browser definitions (e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers) to indicate that iPad is not a mobile device, but that can get complex.

Also, one gotcha to be aware of: apparently [iPad sometimes reports a different user agent](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2011/05/29/Gotcha-iPad-versus-ASPNET.aspx). Your device mode selection logic needs to account for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of pixels available in tablet devices:

```
var isTablet = httpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice && httpContext.Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth > 768
```